# how can i change xcode project from empty view application to singleview application?

Tags: xcode

Xocde(4.3)--
I mean i already created one project (Empty view application)in Xocde 4.3;
but, now i want convert that(Existing ) project  to an single view Application Xcode .

Please clarify this

Answer (score 0):

Solution # 1)

Easiest thing you can do is create a brand new Single View application and then copy the source files from the old project to the new project.

Solution # 2)

You can also add in a User Interface by selecting "New" -> "File..." under Xcode's "File" menu.  Choose the "User Interface" option. It's up to you to decide whether to do Storyboards or XIB files.

Here is what you'll see:

[image: Choose User Interface type]

And of course you'll also have to choose the device family:

[image: Choose Device type]

Comment: do you already have a storyboard or a XIB file or does one need to be added?

Comment: its replacing the file with single view application instead of empty view application.